# Check in docker container if volume is mount

Tags: docker

I have to copy backups file to `\backups` directory but only if directory has been mounted from other, specific server.

On my host machine I can see that directory as:

```
myuser@myserver.com:/home/myuser/backup on /media/storage type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
[...]
volumes:
      - "/media/storage/backups:/backups"
[...]
```

Inside the container I can see that mounted directory as

```
myuser@myserver.com:/home/myuser/backup on /backup type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

However when `myserver.com` server is disconnected, then the mount info doesn't change and is still seen as `fuse.sshfs`.

How to be sure that backup is going to be save to the right directory?